# Rails server dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost

I am trying to install rails on dreamhost. I have followed the following tutorial guide http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Getting_Started_with_Ruby_on_Rails. However once i activate the site and go to it, i get the following errors

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
These are the possible causes:

There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.

A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

The application may not be properly configured. Please check whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any incorrect configurations, and restart this application.
A service that the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that service.

Error message:
Could not find activesupport-3.2.8 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error message is very clear, activesupport 3.2.8 and probably Rails 3.2.8 is not installed, does the hosting support Rails 3.2.8?

Comment: oh i see, i will need to verify that, how can i downgrade?

Comment: I've tried using rails on dreamhost, it is a **nightmare**. I strongly recommend using a VPS instead, shared hosting is not a good platform for a framework as fast-moving as rails.

Comment: ^ this this a thousand times this. Dreamhost and Rails do *not* work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error is because bundler is not able to find the activesupport gem. Most likely you have installed Rails 3.2.8 locally and bundler is searching the system gem and failing to find it.

You should be able to resolve this with a `bundle install --deployment`.

I would make sure to set your environment variables first before running it and make sure they are correct.

`gem env` will show what they are currently set to.

```
export GEM_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
export PATH=~/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

`bundle exec rails console` should also help let you know whats failing.